# How to repeat the rows n times

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, recursive-query

I want to repeat the rows of a table n number of times.

suppose i have a table as below

Tab1

```
A B C
-----
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

and n =9

i want to get the result as below

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
1 2 3
2 3 4
1 2 3
2 3 4
1 2 3
2 3 4
1 2 3
```

I tried with connect by level and not getting the result as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
SQL> with test (a, b, c) as
  2    (select 1, 2, 3 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 3, 4 from dual
  4    ),
  5  temp as
  6    (select a, b, c,
  7       row_number() over (order by column_value, a) rn
  8     from test cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                                              connect by level <= 9
 10                                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 11    )
 12  select a, b, c
 13  from temp
 14  where rn <= 9
 15  order by rn  ;

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         2          3          4
         1          2          3
         2          3          4
         1          2          3
         2          3          4
         1          2          3
         2          3          4
         1          2          3

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- lines #1 - 4 represent your sample data
- CTE `temp` (lines #5 - 11) created all those rows; `row_number` is used to "rank" them, ordered by `column_value` (think of it as of a `level` pseudocolumn, if it is closer to you) and the `a` column value (why? Your sample output suggests so)
- final query (lines #12 - 15) selects the result for `rn <= 9` (as you wanted to get 9 rows)

Comment: thanks any way, but want to get, if n=9 then get only 9 rows

Comment: There *are* 9 rows. (haven't been before, didn't realize what you want at first glance)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is a recursive query. If you want 9 records, then:

```
with cte(a, b, c, rn, cnt, lvl) as (
    select a, b, c, row_number() over(order by a, b, c) rn, count(*) over() cnt, 0 lvl from mytable
    union all 
    select a, b, c, rn, cnt, lvl + 1 from cte where lvl * cnt + rn < 8
)
select a, b, c from cte order by lvl, rn
```

The idea is to enumerate the original rows with `row_number()` and count them. Then we generate new rows, and stop as soon as the target number of rows is reached. This is somehow more efficient than generating more rows than needed, then filtering.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=34590e5b5e1532b7129150b8ef641805)**:

```
 A |  B |  C
-: | -: | -:
 1 |  2 |  3
 2 |  3 |  4
 1 |  2 |  3
 2 |  3 |  4
 1 |  2 |  3
 2 |  3 |  4
 1 |  2 |  3
 2 |  3 |  4
 1 |  2 |  3
```